# JS id case sensitivity acting out

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am working on a website that contains two elements with the same `"id"` (but different case) ie `"freeshipping"` versus `"freeShipping"`. When I try to select the `freeShipping` element in JS, the browser returns the content of `freeshipping` instead. On my coworker's computer it works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea why it would act as case insensitive in this case? I've been looking online and all I can find is people complaining at other people saying "use the same case". However, no answer to my question about why the case sensitivity is not working.

```
<div id="freeshipping" style="display: none; padding: 15px;">
   Free Shipping on orders over $199!
</div>
<span id="freeShipping" class="stock">#freeShippingQualifierText#</span>
```

**EDIT:**

```
$freeShipping = $('#freeShipping');
$freeShipping.text('Free Shipping!');
```

Comment: Show your code where you are "trying to select freeShipping in JS it was returning the content of freeshipping"

Comment: This is browser dependent: [In the DOM are node ids case sensititve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236856/in-the-dom-are-node-ids-case-sensititve)

Answer (score 2):

Having the same id is just asking for trouble. But if you really MUST do it, be context sensitive.

```
$("div#freeshipping").text();
$("span#freeShipping").text();
```

Should work, assuming the browser accepts the IDs.