# HTML Question: I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: html, forms, variable-assignment

I have an HTML assignment. Here's the task...

> [make something that] has:
>
> - an single-line text input with an id of "name",
> - a name of "pet_name",
> - and with an associated label that reads "Name".

I thought I had the right code, but it's saying I got it wrong and this was the feedback I got:

> has exactly one input with a name of 'pet_name' and an associated label with the content 'Name'.

This is the HTML code that I had:

```html
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">
```

Could someone please help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, EHubb!  Welcome to SO!  Your code looks fine, I made a [jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/bupiwoy/edit?html,output), clicking the "Name" label causes the field to be highlighted, which is correct behavior.  My only thought is the proofing may be broken?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, EHubb!  I'm stumped!  Your code is fine.  Where are you validating this/having it checked?  Maybe try wrapping it all in a `<div>...</div>` in one line?  Maybe it wants a very specific format, i.e., `<label>Name<input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name"></label>`?  Let me know, I have no idea.

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking too. It's an assignment for app academy. When I submit the html file, it goes thru it to see if I have all the right code. I'll ask my advisor about it. Cause I don't see anything wrong either. Thank you for you help!

Comment: No problem!  If one of those suggestions works, let me know and I can post an answer or something!

Comment: If I originally had for="Name" with the "N" being a capital letter, would that be wrong?

Comment: It probably would have been wrong, [id's in javascript are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1236856/2430549).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change name="name"
Because for and name both the property have to match.

Comment: Just want to clarify. Change: for="name"  to name="name" ?

Comment: No replace name="pet_name" with name="name".

Comment: I'm even more confused now lol. Where do I put "pet_name" then? It's saying I have to have a name of "pet_name"

Comment: <label for="name">Name</label> 

<input type="text" id="name" name="name">

Comment: I get what you're saying. But where does "pet_name" go? It say's I have to have it

Comment: So change the value of for.
<label for="pet_name">Name</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">

Answer (score 0):

The `for` attribute of the `label` tag has to match the `id` attribute of the `input`  tag it's describing. So in your case, it should be `<label for="name">Name</label>`.

The `name` attribute of the `input` tag is only relevant for sending the values / receiving them after submission of the form.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: I see `<label for="name">Name</label>` already in OP's post?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Well, but that's the way it *does*  work....